# load balancing in apache on jira cluster

Tags: apache, jira

Please help me in configuration my httpd.
I made all what write in off site jira : https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-architecture/jira-data-center/plugin-guide-to-jira-high-availability-and-clustering/configuring-a-jira-cluster-for-plugin-development

But if I go to link I got the simple test page of Apache. But why? 
I'm not understand why balancing is not working.

my httpd.conf (part):

> ```
>     < VirtualHost *:80>
>     ProxyRequests off
>     ServerName jira-cluster.com
>     <Proxy balancer://jiracluster>
>      BalancerMember http://jira1.com:8080 route=node1
>      BalancerMember http://jira2.com:8080 route=node2
>      Order Deny,Allow
>      Deny from none
>      Allow from all
>
>             ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
>             ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
>     </Proxy>
>     <Location /balancer-manager>
>             SetHandler balancer-manager
>
>             Order deny,allow
>             Allow from all
>     </Location>
>
>     ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
>     ProxyPass / balancer://jiracluster/
>     ProxyPreserveHost on 
>    < /VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried swapping * for your domain name
e.g.   < VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>